# Usage of pointer-events:none; with HTML CANVAS

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas

in my web page , I need to display the google map. But my web page also contains canvas elements.

Now if I make the z:index of canvas higher than map I cannot zoom in or pan to left/right.
If i make the z:index of map higher than canvas element,it covers the whole of page as a result i can not see the triangle drawn through the canvas.

I used the css property `pointer-events:none;`   but it only works properly in chrome,and in Mozilla (to good extent). But IE (10) is not using supporting it.

How do I achieve the same .i.e zoom and pan in IE as well.

This is the hmtl part

```
 <section id="intro3" data-navigation-tag="Plan" style="display: block; background-position: 50% 44.866px;">
        <canvas id="amenitycanvas" style="display:none;z-index:2;pointer-events:none;"></canvas>
<div id="link" style="position:absolute;">
           <a href="#" onclick="HideAndShowFunc('LOCATION')">LOCATION</a><br>
        </div>

<div class="image-display" id="displaylocate" style=" width:100%; height:100%;right:0%;top:0%;position:absolute;display:none;z-index:1;"> 
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.co.in/maps?t=m&amp;q=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu,+Mumbai,+Mumbai+Suburban,+Maharashtra&amp;z=14&amp;ll=19.104093,72.840396&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://www.google.co.in/maps?t=m&amp;q=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu,+Mumbai,+Mumbai+Suburban,+Maharashtra&amp;z=14&amp;ll=19.104093,72.840396&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View in Google Map</a></small>
        </div>
</section>
```

and the  javascript

```
function HideAndShowFunc(name)
        {
            if(name=="LOCATION")
           {
                $("#intro3canvas").hide();  
                $("#intro3logo50").hide(); 
                $("#essence-luxury").hide(); 
                $("#displayamenity").hide();
                $("#projlogodiv").hide();
                $("#link").hide();
                $("#intro3Ongoing").hide();
                $("#intro3Upgoing").hide();
                $("#intro3Completed").hide();
                $("#arrow").hide();
                $("#table-frame").hide();               
                $("#intro3bg").hide();
                $("#amenitycanvas").show(); 
                $("#displaylocate").show();
           }
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Hand.js](http://handjs.codeplex.com/). It's polyfill for *pointer-events* and [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/01/16/hand-js-a-polyfill-for-supporting-pointer-events-on-every-browser.aspx) might be help you to use Hand.js

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to place a comment.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, IMHO, fian's response seems more 'answerish' than 'commentish' (assuming hand.js is a good polyfill for adding point-events to non-supporting browsers).  Sometimes you just need a link to point you in the right direction--Pun intended since OP's app involves a map  :-)

Comment: @markE both link-only answers and answers which simply point to a plugin are frowned upon. If they weren't, SO would be full of JavaScript questions whose answers are nothing more than "Check out jQuery!".

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: Granted--answers like "use jquery" are not specific enough to be good answers, but in this case the link seems to be a very specific tool that OP can use to fix their specific problem.  IMHO, Every link-only answer should not be frowned upon. Such answers should rise and fall on the merit of what they provide.  Anyway, that's my 2-cents from my soapbox!  Cheers!